# Xcode 8 UIImagePickerController frozen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I just run into this problem. I can call UIImagePickerController as usual but when I pick an Image(taking a photo or photo library), the "use photo" button and "retake" button don't work, and the UI just freezes.

I have done some debugging and found the code won't get into the delegate method.

I didn't change any code about UIImagePickerController. Everything works just fine before. So I'm wondering why this happened and how to fix this bug?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the code :

```
 UIImagePickerController * imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 [imgPicker setDelegate:self]
 [imgPicker setAllowsEditing:YES];
 [imgPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
 [self.navigationController presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:^{

            }];

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)editingInfo {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

Comment: I also get this in console

warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

 Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

Comment: just in case, check if you've set NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription string in target plist file

Comment: Thank you for your comment,That Will cause crash,In my case, Everything just stuck there.

Comment: Sometime I get this in console
[Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
but not everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure this out.This is caused by using the wrong delegate method.the one I was using has been **DEPRECATED**.

We should use this one

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info;`

and the image information is in the info dictionary.You can get the image in this way

`UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];`

Answer (score 1):

From xcode 8 with ios 10 you have to add some key value to the info.plist for accessing the photos using UIImagepicker Controller

Key     :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Value   : This app requires access to the photo library